Greek letter "Kappa" use in Set Theory
I have been given a definition that the Greek letter "K" is used when a cardinal and ordinal number of a set are the same.  As I have NO knowledge of Set Theory, can someone explain this?  I am guessing that it represents a variable number based on the number in the given finite set being referenced, such as the value of the fifth item in a set of five items, or the thirteenth item when the set contains thirteen items. Is this accurate?  If not, or it is more specific than my postulation, can someone please clarify?

I suggest you see this article How to ask a good question

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It’s more relevant/interesting for infinite sets

Hi! My guess is that you need to back up a bit and understand more about basic set theory first before trying to learn about cardinals and ordinals formally. Yes, informally, cardinals refer to the size of sets, and ordinals refer to the ordering of a set, but this will be intuitive primarily with finite sets, where much of the formality isn't needed.

I removed the descriptive-set-theory tag since I don't think it applies. If you read the description of the tag and are certain that it does apply, you can add it back.

I'm not sure why or in what context you were given this definition, but here's an extremely simplified explanation.
Cardinal numbers and ordinal numbers are two number systems that 'measure' sets. Cardinals extend the familiar idea of 'size' ("one","two","three",...), while ordinals extend the idea of 'position' ("first","second","third"...). They both contain the natural numbers - 0,1,2,3,4,... - but they also have many, many numbers beyond that, with many 'levels' of infinity.
It turns out that all cardinals are ordinals, just like all natural numbers are real numbers.
You probably know that $x$ is the 'default' variable for a real number - we can use any letter we want, but if there's no particular reason a certain letter would be best, we'll just use $x$. But if we're specifically talking about something that has to be a natural number, we'll probably use $n$ instead. (n for natural, I assume?)
Similarly, $\alpha$ is the 'default' for an ordinal number, but if we're specifically talking about something that has to be a cardinal number, we'll probably use $\kappa$ instead. (κ for, uh, κardinal, I guess. Greek doesn't have a nice analogue of 'c'.)
That's all it really is - a commonly-used variable name.
